# How to get record count using reference cursor in oracle10g

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I want to know how we can get record count using reference cursor in oracle10g.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you fetched the rows you can use *cursorname*%rowcount to get the amount of records you fetched.

Comment: That only returns the number of rows currently fetched, not the number of rows in the entire result set (unless you're at the end of the cursor).

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

You can only count the rows while you fetch them from the cursor.

A cursor is like a stream, and Oracle does not know how much rows are in there until it has read them all (which happens as you fetch rows).