# Count no of rows in refcursor?

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I have procedure which has a refcursor as an out parameter . I need to  count the no of rows in a ref cursor and if its exceeds the maximum limit I need to send the error msg.

Please suggest me how to count the rows in the ref cursor

Comment: There is no way to count rows of refcursor except fetching them all.

Comment: @Mani:It is not possible to get the count of the refcursor ,without fetching them .One possible solution "Add another column `count(*) over ()` to the select clause of your cursor ,which will give you the count of the total records in your cursor .So After fetching the first record you get to know the total count in the cursor ,based on that you can proceed with your logic,but this approach is slower and not recomended.

Comment: Check this Post


 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062142/how-to-get-record-count-using-reference-cursor-in-oracle10g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like the following:

```
FUNCTION SOME_FUNC(pin_Count_limit  NUMBER,
                   pout_Cursor      SYS_REFCURSOR)
  RETURN NUMBER  -- returns the number of lines the cursor should return
IS
  strBasic_sql        VARCHAR2(32767) :='SELECT COL1, COL2, COL3 FROM TABLE1';
  cursorOut           SYS_REFCURSOR;
  cursorCount         SYS_REFCURSOR;
  nCount              NUMBER;
  bCursor_out_open    BOOLEAN := FALSE;
  bCursor_count_open  BOOLEAN := FALSE;
BEGIN
  OPEN cursorCount FOR 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (' || strBasic_sql || ')';
  bCursor_count_open := TRUE;
  FETCH cursorCount INTO nCount;
  CLOSE cursorCount;
  bCursor_count_open := FALSE;

  IF nCount < pin_Count_limit THEN
    OPEN cursorOut FOR strBasic_sql;
    bCursor_out_open := TRUE;
    pout_Cursor := cursorOut;
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Cursor returns too many rows');
  END IF;

  RETURN nCount;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    IF bCursor_count_open = TRUE THEN
      CLOSE cursorCount;
    END IF;

    IF bCursor_out_open = TRUE THEN
      CLOSE cursorOut;
    END IF;

    RAISE;
END SOME_PROC;
```

Note that due to activity in the database between the time that the 'count' cursor is opened and the time that the 'real' cursor is opened it's possible that the number of rows returned by the 'real' cursor might differ from what is expected.

Share and enjoy.